# Which should I use? A view or a new table using a MERGE statement to reflect a remote table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I have table "A" that is located on a remote server that gets emptied at random times everyday.

We want to be able to keep that data longer than that. We can only view that table and not change anything with it so, I'm making a table "B" that is on local server that will hold that data longer.

Should I make a new table on local server that uses a MERGE statement to "mirror" table "A" then do a LEFT JOIN INSERT from "mirror" into table "B" or should I just create a view for table "A" and INSERT results into table "B".

The reason behind my question is I had to convert a DTSX file into a stored procedure that was doing this task for another similar table. I used a MERGE statement for this because someone had created a table to mirror remote table then INSERT from it into correct table. I had no idea if an application was utilizing that mirror table for something so I kept it and just used a MERGE statement to continue the mirror without the use of the DTSX.

Now I'm wondering if there are any pro's or con's for either way so I can do it the best way possible for this new table.

Comment: If you `MERGE` the data, you have no need to then do an `INSERT`. The `MERGE` could handle your `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, *and* `DELETE`.

Comment: @Larnu Is it possible to leave out the `DELETE` portion of the `MERGE` or is it required?  Since the remote table gets dropped at random points and I want to save that data for a longer time.

Comment: I said "*could*" not must.

Comment: Nice, then it's probably best to go with a `MERGE` in this case because `UPDATE` portion can be a possibility. You should post as an answer so I can accept it.